# JQuery get all items in a list

Tags: jquery

Could someone help me out with this JQuery?

I have a bunch of list items, and when clicking one of them, I want to remove the class attribute 'selected' from each list item in the same UL.

I have a javascript function:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

function clearSelectedCSS(item) {

    $(item).parent().$('li.itemselected').removeClass('itemselected');

}
</script>
```

It is called via the onclick part of each LI, and 'this' is passed.

I can't quite figure out the JQuery, could someone give me a pointer? My code basically wants to select the item that was clicked, get its parent, then select all list items that belong to that parent (ie, every li in the list that was clicked that has class 'itemselected'), then remove the class 'itemselected' from them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $(item).parent().find('li.itemselected').removeClass('itemselected');
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to get the `.parent()` when you can just grab [the `.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
$(item).siblings('.itemselected').removeClass('itemselected');
```

This will be more efficient, because `.parent().find()` will test *all* descendant elements. Even if you did `.parent().children()`, you're adding an unnecessary traversal.

---

**EDIT:** I'm not sure from the question if you want to include the one that was clicked in the class removal.

If so, you could do this:

```
$(item).parent().children('.itemselected').removeClass('itemselected');
```

or

```
$(item).siblings().andSelf().filter('.itemselected').removeClass('itemselected');
```

Comment: See my answer for why these are not equivalent.

Comment: @lonesomeday - We have effectively the same answer. What is not equivalent?

Comment: $(item).parent().children() includes the original item, $(item).siblings() does not.

Comment: @lonesomeday - My answer is to use `.siblings()` not `.parent().children()`. I was just commenting that while `.children()` is more efficient than `.find()`, it is still less efficient than `.siblings()`.

Comment: I realise this.  My point is that the result of $(item).parent().children() is not the same as $(item).siblings().  This needs to be clear.  Otherwise, I agree with your post.

Comment: @lonesomeday - ok, I see what you're getting at.

Comment: Yes, that's the nice way to do it. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all lis except the one that was clicked, you can use `$().siblings()`:

```
$(item).siblings('li.itemselected').removeClass('itemselected');
```

Using `parent().find('li.itemselected')` will include the `<li>` that was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with this until I got this to work:

```
<head>    
<script>
   function clearSelectedCSS(item) {
      $('#' + item.parentElement.id + ' > li').removeClass('exampleClass');
   }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1">
   <ul id="List1">
      <li class="exampleClass" onclick="clearSelectedCSS(this)">First Item</li>
      <li class="exampleClass" onclick="clearSelectedCSS(this)">Second Item</li>
      <li class="exampleClass" onclick="clearSelectedCSS(this)">Third Item</li>
   </ul>

   <ul id="List2">
      <li class="exampleClass" onclick="clearSelectedCSS(this)">Fourth Item</li>
      <li class="exampleClass" onclick="clearSelectedCSS(this)">Fifth Item</li>
      <li class="exampleClass" onclick="clearSelectedCSS(this)">Sixth Item</li>
   </ul>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, I had to address the parent of the item to get the `<ul>` container object, and then used the `>` child selector to get the collection of `<li>`. At that point the `.removeClass()` call works correctly. Hope that helps--